# How to Extract each number in a string (PowerBI)?

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a free form column that includes numbers and characters. My goal is to be able to extract each number into its own column. Calculated Columns or M code is fine. Here is an example:

```
Segment  Notes
1        WO# 1234567 Call Tony @ 623-623-6236 30 prior to arrival
2        Replaced 2 Hoses 7654321
3        Opened WO5674321 on 11/20/2019
```

Ultimately What I need is each number in each observation in its own column like this:

```
Segment  Notes                                                       Num1      Num2          Num3
1        WO# 1234567 Call Tony @ 623-623-6236 30 prior to arrival    1234567   623-692-9493  30
2        Replaced 2 Hoses 7654321                                    2         7654321
3        Opened WO5674321 on 11/20/2019                              5674321   11/20/2019
```

If it is too difficult to extract dates and phone numbers in their entirety I can live with each element going into its own column. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an 'is value' function we can take advantage of.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("LY0xC8IwFIT/yvFcK/a9tClugku3gAgdQoagGQohCakI/fdGEe6m7+POWmLqaDEHsKhh1BOuPkbcc9pxgRZ1/FdD9Sh1zRWvDF/r+vaRXGdJ2sAtlOgf4QnBnLewYdLjoIR/gmqCKSE1vJh28QXICcwn6Vv4TM59AA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Segment = _t, Notes = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.ToList([Notes]),each if Value.Is(Value.FromText(_), type number) or List.Contains({" ", "-", "/"}, _) then _ else null))))

in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]